# Icecream close-up - What nodes am I missing?

Tags: node-editor, procedural

I'm trying to reproduce this ice cream from [another blender
forum](https://blenderartists.org/t/ice-cream/1130096). Yet I'm miles away from this artist's work. What nodes or settings am I missing?

What I want:
[image: pic]

What I have:
[image: pic]

Reference hi-res download: https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/4/3/f/43fd66535d47ddccf47d6b52734453f795309766.jpeg

[image]

Comment: Hey :). Here is a procedural shader that looks good [on Blendswap](https://www.blendswap.com/blend/27443). For inspiration.

Comment: @JachymMichal Thank you, yes tried that one as well

Comment: When I see the melting overhang clifs ... I dont think this is done just procedurally (since even microdisplacement can't handle this kind of shape. Or you are looking for something that looks similar but in procedural way?

Comment: @vklidu >Or you are looking for something that looks similar but in procedural way?

If it looks similar, yes (hope I understood you correctly)

Comment: I mean those details are not probably procedural https://imgur.com/fxb9y0Q but sculpted or simulated ... and I don't want to say I know How-To ... I'm just asking for others what is your goal ... if to get those detail even without procedural or you'r looking for only procedural way and you don't care to reach your reference.

Comment: @vklidu Important point, thank you. Goal is similarity. Fixing question right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*I tried to get closer to your reference, but by checking real shots it seems to me I just multiplied wrong interpretation of reality :) Of course it has hundreds of possible looks, but version in your reference looks weird to me ;) Anyway ...*

---

*Wave* texture can't create a *zebra* strips, that is what I see as bigger breaks on surface.
For that I based material on **Gabor** texture, it's OSL texture (so only CPU and Cycles shader). Gabor texture is part of Templates in Blender's *Text Editor*.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Later I will add blend file to test it. If you need more details let me know.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254461083_Gabor_Noise_by_Example is now going to be my bed-time reading.... :)

Comment: @vklidu Speechless about your incredible work. Can't wait to reproduce your node setup...fighting murphy's law for now :) Gabor script crashes blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/223826/segmentation-fault-if-adding-gabor-osl-script-node

Comment: @412p9wej I would like to ask you to delete comments ... system is nervous from frequency :) Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Here's everything I know about melting ice cream aside from the taste.

[image]

A procedural solution would be to mix a *Magic Texture* and a *Noise Texture* for the noisy mask, and use a *Wave Texture* with a high *Distortion* value for the outside melted part.

If you just add these masks together, however, you'll get these jagged peaks on the outside, which is not desirable.

[image]

Instead we want to *Subtract* the wave mask from the noise mask first, and then *Add* the result to the wave mask.

This will generate us some nice smooth curvature with noise on the inside.

[image]

I messed with some *ColorRamps*, but I couldn't get anything that I was super pleased with.  The core principles are here, though.  I used the same map to drive the roughness.

[image]