# Segmentation fault if adding gabor.osl script node

Tags: scripting, node-editor, osl

In shading, after adding the script node, I select **gabor_noise.osl** ...

```
shader gabor_noise(
    point Point = P,
    vector Direction = vector(1, 0, 0),
    int Anisotropic = 0,
    float Bandwidth = 1.0,
    float Impulses = 16,
    output float Gabor = 0.8)
{
    Gabor = noise("gabor", Point,
                  "direction", Direction,
                  "anisotropic", Anisotropic,
                  "do_filter", 1, // Set to 0 to disable filtering/anti-aliasing 
                  "bandwidth", Bandwidth,
                  "impulses", Impulses);
}
```

... which in turn crashes blender.

`$ sudo prime-run blender`

```
Read prefs: /root/.config/blender/2.92/config/userpref.blend
DEBUG:BlenderGIS-225.core.checkdeps:GDAL Python binding unavailable
DEBUG:BlenderGIS-225.core.checkdeps:PyProj unavailable
DEBUG:BlenderGIS-225.core.checkdeps:Pillow available
DEBUG:BlenderGIS-225.core.checkdeps:ImageIO Freeimage plugin available
Read blend: /home/me/src/blender/shark/shark.blend
ERROR (bke.fcurve): ../source/blender/blenkernel/intern/fcurve_driver.c:1035 dri
Writing: /home/me/src/blender/shark/tmp/shark.crash.txt
/usr/bin/prime-run: line 2:  1067 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia "$@"
```

`$ cat shark.crash.txt`

```
# Blender 2.92.0, Commit date: 2021-02-24 16:25, Hash 02948a2cab44
bpy.ops.node.select(wait_to_deselect_others=True, mouse_x=1163, mouse_y=815, extend=False, deselect_all=True)  # Operator
bpy.context.space_data.context = 'OUTPUT'  # Property
bpy.context.space_data.context = 'RENDER'  # Property
bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = 'CPU'  # Property
bpy.ops.node.add_node(type="ShaderNodeScript", use_transform=True)  # Operator
bpy.ops.node.translate_attach_remove_on_cancel(TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(-409.649, 215.419, 0), "orient_type":'GLOBAL', "orient_matrix":((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "mirror":True, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":0.793446, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":True, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False, "use_automerge_and_split":False}, NODE_OT_attach={}, NODE_OT_insert_offset={})  # Operator
bpy.data.materials["gabor"].node_tree.nodes["Script"].mode = 'INTERNAL'  # Property
bpy.data.materials["gabor"].node_tree.nodes["Script"].script = bpy.data.texts["gabor_noise.osl"]  # Property

# backtrace
blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x34) [0x558e3aab67e4]
blender(+0xe14cfd) [0x558e3858dcfd]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x3cf80) [0x7f5a2c3e6f80]
/usr/lib/libjemalloc.so.2(+0x4c9d4) [0x7f5a35b079d4]
/usr/lib/libjemalloc.so.2(+0x14ec7) [0x7f5a35acfec7]
/usr/lib/libjemalloc.so.2(+0x16c3b) [0x7f5a35ad1c3b]
/usr/lib/libjemalloc.so.2(+0x74e29) [0x7f5a35b2fe29]
/usr/lib/libjemalloc.so.2(+0x114b6) [0x7f5a35acc4b6]
/usr/lib/libjemalloc.so.2(_ZdlPvm+0xf) [0x7f5a35b343df]
/usr/lib/liboslcomp.so.1.11(_ZN9OSL_v1_113pvt11SymbolTable11delete_symsEv+0x4b) [0x7f5a32eb734b]
/usr/lib/liboslcomp.so.1.11(_ZN9OSL_v1_113pvt15OSLCompilerImplD1Ev+0x273) [0x7f5a32ea6543]
/usr/lib/liboslcomp.so.1.11(_ZN9OSL_v1_1111OSLCompilerD1Ev+0x12) [0x7f5a32ea67a2]
blender(+0x2b42335) [0x558e3a2bb335]
blender(+0x217f7a4) [0x558e398f87a4]
/usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(+0x14cab2) [0x7f5a2e914ab2]
/usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(_PyObject_MakeTpCall+0x30d) [0x7f5a2e8fae9d]
/usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5023) [0x7f5a2e8f6b73]
/usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x1aa) [0x7f5a2e9029ea]
/usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x3c5) [0x7f5a2e8f1f15]
/usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x1aa) [0x7f5a2e9029ea]
/usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x498f) [0x7f5a2e8f64df]
/usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x1aa) [0x7f5a2e9029ea]
blender(+0x16f84ce) [0x558e38e714ce]
blender(+0x165905d) [0x558e38dd205d]
blender(+0x16138fc) [0x558e38d8c8fc]
blender(+0x1563cab) [0x558e38cdccab]
blender(+0x1a7ee30) [0x558e391f7e30]
blender(+0x1a90b59) [0x558e39209b59]
blender(+0x119ee90) [0x558e38917e90]
blender(+0x119f51c) [0x558e3891851c]
blender(wm_event_do_handlers+0x298) [0x558e38918b88]
blender(WM_main+0x22) [0x558e3890ee52]
blender(main+0x367) [0x558e385575a7]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xd5) [0x7f5a2c3d1b25]
blender(_start+0x2e) [0x558e3858a0ae]

# Python backtrace
  File "/usr/share/blender/2.92/scripts/addons/cycles/osl.py", line 30 in osl_compile
  File "/usr/share/blender/2.92/scripts/addons/cycles/osl.py", line 91 in update_script_node
  File "/usr/share/blender/2.92/scripts/addons/cycles/__init__.py", line 103 in update_script_node
```

`$ sudo prime-run blender --version`

```
Blender 2.92.0
        build date: 2021-04-25
        build time: 11:39:34
        build commit date: 2021-02-24
        build commit time: 16:25
        build hash: 02948a2cab44
        build platform: Linux
        build type: Release
        build c flags:  -Wall -Wcast-align -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=return-type -Werror=vla -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Wundef -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Wformat-signedness -Wrestrict -Wnonnull -Wabsolute-value -Wuninitialized -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -fuse-ld=gold -fopenmp -std=gnu11 -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -ffp-contract=off -msse2  
        build c++ flags:  -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-sign-compare -Wlogical-op -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Werror=return-type -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Wformat-signedness -Wrestrict -Wuninitialized -Wundef -Wmissing-declarations -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -I /usr/include/python3.9 -fuse-ld=gold -fopenmp -std=c++17 -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -ffp-contract=off -msse2  
        build link flags:  -Wl,--version-script='/build/blender/src/blender/source/creator/blender.map'
        build system: CMake
```

Does it relate to building blender [for scripting](https://github.com/TylerGubala/blenderpy) by myself?
[Similar problem](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/segmentation-fault-when-running-custom-built-bpy/11284/18).

Comment: The easiest way is to download official build to test if crash's too as your build. Or try to Load factory settings under File menu > Defaults. Sorry I can't help with reading crash log.